# Proof that $\overline{A}=X \setminus \text{ext}(A) $

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, solution-verification, proof-explanation

**Proposition:**

> $\overline{A}=X \setminus \text{ext}(A) $

**Proof given in class:**

Assume $x\notin A \Rightarrow \exists U, x\in U, A\cap U \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow U\in X-A \Rightarrow x\in \mathring{(X-A)} \Rightarrow x\notin X-\mathring{(X-A)}$

Which supposedly proves the entire thing? Doesn't it only prove  $X \setminus \text{ext}(A)\subseteq \overline{A}\;$  by the contrapositive?

If indeed this is wrong, here is my attempt. $\supseteq$   inclusion that my proof is wrong anyway I think:

$x\in U, A\cap U \neq \emptyset \Rightarrow \exists y\in{U}, y\notin{X-A} \Rightarrow y\in X \setminus \text{ext}(A) \Rightarrow U\cap{(X \setminus \text{ext}(A))}\neq \emptyset$

And, since this holds for every $U$ we have the inclusion $$\overline A\subseteq X \setminus \text{ext}(A),$$
since every adherent point of $A$ is also an adherent point of $X \setminus \text{ext}(A)$. I thinks this last sentence is wrong.

Comment: $\overline A$ is defined as $\cap F$ where $F$ is the family of all closed subsets of $X $ that have $A$ as a subset.  And $ext(A)$ is defined as $\cup G$ where $G$ is the family of all open subsets of $X$ that are disjoint from $A.$ We have $X\setminus ext(A)=X\setminus \cup G=\cap \{X \setminus g:g\in G\}=\cap F=\overline X$ because  $\{X \setminus g:g\in G\}=F.$

Comment: On formatting: You can use \implies for $\implies$ and \iff for $\iff$. The more common notation for $\{x\in B:x\not\in C\}$ is $B\setminus C$, formatted as B\setminus C or B\backslash C. Also most people don't mind when terms like ext get italicized so you can just write ext instead of \text {ext}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $A$ and any $x \in X$. There are two mutually exclusive conditions:

1. Every (open) neighbourhood of $x$ intersects $A$.
2. There is some (open) neighbourhood $U$ of $x$ that is disjoint  from $A$ (or $U \subseteq X\setminus A)$.

If 1 holds $x \in \overline{A}$ and vice versa and if 2 holds then $x \in \operatorname{ext}(A)$ and vice versa.

So by mutual exclusivity

$$x \in \overline{A} \iff x \notin \operatorname{ext}(A)$$ which shows the equality.

Comment: how to go from $x\in X\A$ to $x\in ext(A)$?

Comment: @Goob a neighbourhood inside $X\setminus A$ is what $\operatorname{ext}(A)$ means.

Comment: $ext(A)=\mathring{X-A}$ no?

Comment: @Goob yes that’s the same condition.

Comment: oh so x is in an open neighborhood of a closed set, but U is open so it must be contained in the greatest open set which is ext(A). Am I understanding correctly?

Comment: @Goob yes, $x$ is *one* open set inside $X-A$ so also in the *largest* open subset of it, $\operatorname{ext}(A)$.

Answer (score 0):

You can prove that $\forall A \in X$, $X=\text{int}(A) \cup \text{ext} (A) \cup \partial (A)$ and since $\bar{A} =A \cup \partial A = \text{int}(A) \cup \partial A$, then $\bar{A} = X - \text{ext}(A)$.

For the first proof note that $\text{int}(A) \cap \text{ext}(A) = \text{int}(A) \cap \partial A = \text{ext}(A) \cap \partial A= \emptyset $.